# Check times span over two days as well as within the same day using momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Given the following two times without dates and using moment, how can I best check the following two scenarios based on 24 hours times:

1)

```
let startTime = "22:00:00";
let endTime = "02:00:00";
```

Using the `startTime` I need to set some flag (boolean) indicating that the `endTime` has spanned over to the next day and not within the same 24 hour period of the `startTime`?

2)

```
let startTime = "22:00:00";
let endTime = "23:53:00";
```

the same as item (1) but this time setting a flag indicating that the `startTime` and `endTime` are within the same 24 hour period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet. Took the liberty to replace `let` by `const`, as there are no expected modifications to the variables.

```js
const startTime_1 = "22:00:00";
const endTime_1 = "02:00:00";

const momentStart_1 = moment(startTime_1, 'hh:mm:ss');
const momentEnd_1 = moment(endTime_1, 'hh:mm:ss');

const hasSpanned_1 = momentStart_1.isAfter(momentEnd_1);
console.log(`${startTime_1} -> ${endTime_1} ==> Spanned: ${hasSpanned_1}`); // true.

const startTime_2 = "22:00:00";
const endTime_2 = "23:53:00";

const momentStart_2 = moment(startTime_2, 'hh:mm:ss');
const momentEnd_2 = moment(endTime_2, 'hh:mm:ss');

const hasSpanned_2 = momentStart_2.isAfter(momentEnd_2);
console.log(`${startTime_2} -> ${endTime_2} ==> Spanned: ${hasSpanned_2}`); // true.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```